# Why is the sum of a list multiplied by the number of its combinations the sum of all combinations

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I very recently stumbled upon this relation. If we have $n$ numbers and we want to see how many combinations are of those $n$ numbers, we can put $n$ into exponent with base 2. So we get $2^{n}$. However why is the sum of all combinations equal to $2^n$ times the sum of $n$.

So mathematically my question is:
We have given numbers $a_0, a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$, and then the following holds:
$$2^n\sum_{k=0}^n a_k = \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\cdot \sum_{j=0}^n a_j\right)$$

Why does it hold?

(Please take a look if I made a mistake at endpoints of sums, it could be $n+1$or maybe $n-1$ somewhere. However I hope you get the main idea of what my question is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are familiar with the identity

$$\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$$

This is simply an application of this identity. Start by rewriting $2^n$ as the sum, and then pull the constant into the sum like this:

$$2^n \sum_{k=0}^n a_k = \left(\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^n a_j\right) = \sum_{k=0}^n \left[\binom{n}{k} \sum_{j = 0}^n a_j\right]$$

Comment: +1 though you have a typo in the middle of your second expression when you say $a_n$.  Personally I would find it clearer if you said something like $$2^n \sum_{k=0}^n a_k = 2^n \sum_{j=0}^n a_j = \left(\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^n a_j\right) = \sum_{k=0}^n \left[\binom{n}{k} \sum_{j = 0}^n a_j\right]$$